# Use UID as map key in Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm building a chat app with Firestore and each chat room has a map of participants like so:

[image]

The keys are the corresponding UIDs of the users. I want to use this map to decide which user can access a chat.
In my security rules, I currently check if the logged-in user's UID exists in this map to allow read and write access:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participants
```

But this only checks if the user is in this map, not if the value is actually true. I want to check that as well.

What I basically want is something like this:

```
allow read, write: if resource.data.participants.request.auth.uid == true
```

But this does not actually work. How do I use the current user's UID as the key in a map check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use square brackets to index into the [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) using any string expression you want:

```
allow read, write: if resource.data.participants[request.auth.uid] == true
```

Comment: I was close :) Thank you very much, that was incredibly fast!